# ValueError: could not convert string to float: pi

Tags: python, math

i'm making a program (w/python 2.7) to approximate sin(x) with taylor series, here's the code:

```
from math import pi
from math import sin
from math import factorial
x=float(raw_input("Degree(in radian, example: 5*pi/4): "))
n=input("n: ")
Sum=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    Sum=Sum+(pow(-1,(i+1))*pow(x,(2*i-1))/factorial(2*i-1))
error=math.fabs(sin(x)-Sum)
print "Using Taylor series for sin(%s) with n = %d returns %f,with error= %f"(x,n,Sum,error)
```

(sorry for the `from math import` mess up there, not exactly good with this)

however, when run with x = 5*pi/4, the program returns

> ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 5*pi/4

what am I doing wrong here? I think that python reads x as a string and fails to float that, but what do I know

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Python's `float()` function doesn't understand `'5*pi/4'` any more than it understands `'airspeed of an unladen swallow plus two'`. You have to pass it a floating-point number or its string representation, like `'4'` or `'2.5883'`.

Comment: Don't bother learning Python 2, rather switch to Python 3 directly. The `raw_input()` equivalent is called `input()` there and `print` is a function. The rest should be mostly the same. That said, you can hardcode the input value to get closer to the required minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, python does read x as a string:

```
y = raw_input("Degree(in radian, example: 5*pi/4): ")
print y => 5*pi/4
```

You would have to precompute the value in radian and pass it to your program:

```
(5 * math.pi)/2 = 7.853981633974483
```

This would be the value you give as input to your program.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a solution for achieving what you want. Read the documentation of the Python 2 `input()` function before using this solution though. The documentation also explains the reason it was removed in Python 3!

Here's the code:

```
from math import pi
x = input()
print x
```

If you run this code and input `3 * pi`, it will print `9.42477796076938`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take values in the a*pi/b format from the command line, you can use the following.

```
x=(raw_input("Degree(in radian, example: 5*pi/4): "))
numerator =  float (x.split('*')[0])
denominator =float (x.split('/')[1]) 
x = numerator* pi /denominator
```